# Pegar atributos de um objeto usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço para pegar os atributos de um objeto que é retornado por uma *action* no *javascript*?

Esse é meu código *ajax*.

Passo o *id* para a action e ela retorna um objeto. Gostaria de acessar os valores desse objeto.

```
function UpdateDataPortfolio(id) {
    var parametros = {
        cd: id,
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ManagementTables/UpdateDataPotfolio",
        data: parametros,
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('failure');
        }
    });
}
```

Essa é a *action*:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public Portfolio UpdateDataPotfolio(String cd)
    {
        if (cd != null)
        {
            Portfolio port = portfolio.ListbyId(cd);
            return port;
        }


        return new Portfolio();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Para fins de debug(que parece ser seu caso) use o [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log):

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
},
```

Para acessar as propriedades de um objeto, use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
success: function (data) {
    var keys = Object.keys(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    }
},
```

Em relação a parte do Asp.Net, talvez você devesse usar o [ActionResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx) para retornar seu objeto:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateDataPotfolio(string cd)
{
    // retorno
    return Json(port);
}
```

E na sua chamada ajax, trocar `dataType: "html"` para `dataType: "json"`, pois você está esperando um *json*, como definido nos [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings). Então o método [`Json()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.118).aspx) se encarrega de transformar sua classe `Portifolio` em json para ser lido corretamente no retorno. Não sei se entendi bem a sua intenção nessa request, se não, por favor me avise.

Comment: Existe ainda o `JsonResult`, que considero melhor que o `ActionResult` para este caso.

Comment: Consegui usando o Json. Obrigado

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez boa opção também.

Comment: @Paulo se essa é resposta da pergunta, favor marca-la como tal.

Answer (score 0):

Quando for acessar atributos, considere que o elemento é acessado da seguinte forma:

**Por classe(s):**
`'.nome_classe1, .nome_classe_2'`
**Por Id(s):**
`'#elem_1, #elem_2'`
**Por elemento(s):**
`'body, html, div'`
Passe a lista dentro do objeto em jQuery `$('aqui')`
E para alterar atributos: `$('obj').attr('nome_atributo','novo_valor');`
Para pegar o valor de um atributo: `$('obj').attr('nome_atributo');`

Você pode acessar os valores pela ID do objeto, através do método `.val()`
Exemplo:

```
function getObj(id)
{
   var valor = $('#'+id).val();
   console.log(valor);
}
```

Caso o elemento sejá uma div, você pode acessar através do método `.text()`, se for um texto ou `.html()`, caso seja um conteúdo em HTML.

Comment: Na verdade acho que você entendeu errado. O OP queria acessar as propriedades(ok, ele chamou de atributos) de um *objeto* javascript e não de um *elemento* DOM.

Comment: A pergunta me pareceu meio confusa mesmo.